# ArcGIS JS API 3.21 InfoTemplate ZoomIn Button

Tags: gis, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Has anyone had luck attaching a click event to a custom button built in the HTML of the InfoTemplate?  Here's my InfoTemplate HTML:

```
uploadInfoTemplate = new InfoTemplate ({
    title: "",
    content: "<strong>Segment:</strong> ${segment}" +
             "<hr/>" +
             "<strong>Time:</strong> <i>${dateTime}</i>" +
             "<div style='width: 100%; text-align:right;'>" +
                 "<input class='zoomButton' type='button' value='Zoom to' />" +
             "</div>"
});
```

I then have hidden items on the default InfoTemplate, i.e. the zoomTo link.  I want to simply replace the zoomTo's functionality with a button, to make it look a little nicer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to just improve the look of the "Zoom To" button, a few lines of CSS can do the trick:

```
a.action.zoomTo {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #a8abaf;
  border: solid #a8abaf;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
    a.action.zoomTo:hover{
      background-color: #898b8e;
      border: solid #898b8e;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry @Jeremy Swagger,

I forgot I had fixed this and forgot to update my question.  I came up with a solution like this:

```
if(this.zoomButton) {
    domConstruct.destroy(this.zoomButton);
{

var zoomToButtonHTML = '<div style="width 100%;"><input class="zoomButton" type="button" value="Zoom to" /></div>';

this.zoomButton = domConstruct.create("div", {
    "class": "action",
    "id": "uploadLink",
    "innerHTML": zoomToButtonHTML
}, query(".actionList, this.map.infoWindow.domNode)[0]);

var self=this;
on(this.zoomButton, 'click', function(evt) {
    self._zoomToPoint(evt. self.map);
});
```

with CSS of:

```
.zoomButton {
    background: linear-gradient(#666666, #3F4041);
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 0,2em;
}

.zoomButton:hover {
    background: #333333;
}
```